# How to remove automatically a url parameter (set as UrlParameter.Optional in global.asax) when using ActionLink method in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little issue:

Let' assume that I have the following route setting (the default) **but I have more other routes with different optional url parameter names**.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
       action = "Index", 
       id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I create a breadcrumb menu using a simple logic:

```
foreach(var item in RouteData.Values){
   if(item.Key.Equals("controller")) {
      url = htmlHelper.ActionLink("Link text", "Index", item.Key).ToHtmlString();
   }
    ...
}
```

Well, when I am on `http://localhost:1234/` then breadcrumb url returns fine. `http://localhost:1234/Home/Index`.

But when access `http://localhost:1234/Home/Index/1` then anchor url for current controller (in breadcrumb side) becomes like as url from browser (same value,  `http://localhost:1234/Home/Index/1`).

It is possible to remove automatically url parameter set as  `UrlParameter.Optional` in Global.asax in order to do not display in anchor url ?

**`id` is simple case, I have many routes and different names for optional url parameter**.

Thanks

Comment: Your breadcrumb shouldn't even work because item.Key would be 'controller', and the action link should then try to go to /controller/Index... can you post the real code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in global.asax. Yo cannot change a method behavior in that way. It makes no sense: your app would stop working as expected.

However, you can use [this overload os GenerateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703536%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) supplying an empty RouteValueDictionary. In this way you can get rid of the present route data (which includes the current request parameters, like the id in your url).

```
public static string GenerateUrl(
    string routeName,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    RouteCollection routeCollection,
    RequestContext requestContext,
    bool includeImplicitMvcValues
)
```

This will give you a Url with which you can create your action link.

Comment: I don't want to use Global.asax, I want to generate URL for breadcrumb without put in url that optional parameter...How to do that in C# code ?

Comment: Have you tried the GenerateUrl method from my answer? Any difficulty?